# Laravel get record from database in blade view

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to known how to get data from database in blade like from User table:

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

I have table `user_settings`

I would like to get record from this table by logged user id like this:

```
{{ UserSettings::user()->my_field }}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: try {{ UserSettings::user()->my_field ->get()}}

Comment: return view("your view", ["userSettings" =>UserSettings::user()]);  now $userSettigs is available in your view

Comment: DO not make database calls from your view layer, pass the data from the controller

Comment: Yes, but I must get one field in my header panel? When this panel are inclued in layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this on your blade view

```
{{ \App\UserSettings::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first()->my_field }}
```

In default, model file is inside App folder.

Such direct access to database table is not preferred though, you can return this as a variable from controller function like,

```
$field = \App\UserSettings::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first()->my_field;  
return view('view_name',comapact('field'));
```

and use in blade like

```
{{$field}}
```

Another good way is posted by [Orkhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5555803/orkhan-alikhanov) in another answer using eloquent relationship.
Hope you understand.

Comment: Yes, but in my `UserSettings` model I don't have `user()` function and I gets `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::user()`

Comment: Did you have user_id on user setting table ?

Comment: Yes I have this field

Comment: @lukassz So please close the question by accepting it

Answer (score 2):

You need to retrieve the `UserSettings` associated to the authenticated user:

```
UserSettings::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first()->my_field
```

You can defined a method named `current()` to return that for you.

```
class UserSettings extends Model
{
    public static function current()
    {
        return UserSettings::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first()
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
UserSettings::current()
```

On the other had it would better to use [one-to-one relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) on user model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function settings()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserSettings');
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
Auth::user()->settings->my_field
```